# Sum of all products in MultiDimensional Array

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array, sum

I was wondering how to sum all data in a multi dimensional array.

This is my add function to make a sum of all data in the multidimensional array.

```
private int sum2D(int[,] week)
    {
        int sum = 0; 

        foreach (int d in week)
            sum += d;

        return sum;
    }
```

this just returns a zero amount and I am curious why it does not work and this is my array:

```
int[,] week = new int[4, 5];
```

and this is what determines the values in my array:

```
for (int Row = 0; Row < week.GetLength(0); Row++)
                {
                    if (Row == 0)
                    {
                        Week = "Week 1  ";
                    }
                    else if (Row == 1)
                    {
                        Week = "Week 2  ";
                    }
                    else if (Row == 2)
                    {
                        Week = "Week 3  ";
                    }
                    else if (Row == 3)
                    {
                        Week = "Week 4  ";
                    }
                    Output += "\r\n" + Week + ": ";
                    for (int Col = 0; Col < week.GetLength(1); Col++)
                    {
                        if (Col == 0)
                        {
                            Day = "Monday";
                        }
                        else if (Col == 1)
                        {
                            Day = "Tuesday";
                        }
                        else if (Col == 2)
                        {
                            Day = "Wednesday";
                        }
                        else if (Col == 3)
                        {
                            Day = "Thursday";
                        }
                        else if (Col == 4)
                        {
                            Day = "Friday";
                        }

                        string value = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.InputBox("Enter the amount of products made on " + Day + " for " + Week, "Product Amount");
                        Output += "   ";
                        Output += Int32.Parse(value) + "      ";
                        txtOutput.Text = Output;
                    }
```

Comment: isn't `new int[4, 5]` a one dimensional array and not multidimensional?

Comment: Where do you populate your array?

Comment: @tomasbasham nope, the [C# Language Specification](https://www.microsoft.com/download/details.aspx?id=70299) states that *"The rank of an array type is given by the leftmost rank-specifier in the array-type: A rank-specifier indicates that the array is an array with a rank of one plus the number of “ , ” tokens in the rank-specifier. […] The type int[][,,][,] is a single-dimensional array of three-dimensional arrays of two-dimensional arrays of  int ."*

Comment: @Albireo Thanks, that clears it up

Comment: sum = 0  because you never put anything in the array. You only use it in the 'for' to increase the `Output`. I'm not sure what you would want to achieve with the sum, so could you clarify?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to set the values of every entry within the array when in inner loop:

```
for (int Col = 0; Col < week.GetLength(1); Col++)
{
    // ...

    week[Row, Col] = Convert.ToInt32(value);
}
```

Assuming your `value` is a number holding the amount of products traded/produced on a particular day within a given week.